# Trigger Azure Pipelines build via API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-task

I made a working Azure Pipeline to build my codebase.

Looking for a way to trigger the Azure Pipelines build via API, ideally REST. If REST is not possible, perhaps I could try invoking the build via Azure Functions using a resource ID of sorts.
I would like my own repository monitor to issue an API request that would trigger the build when my conditions are met.
Another question - is it possible to set "pipeline variables" via API - e.g. I make an API call passing values to be used as my pipeline variables' values then triggers the build.

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [VSTS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/queue?view=vsts-rest-4.1) or [DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to queue the build by giving the ID

**VSTS POST:**

```
https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1
```

**DevOps POST:**

```
https://dev.azure.com/account/project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

**Body**

```
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": number
        } 
}
```

[Refer to this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483072/how-to-queue-a-new-build-using-vsts-rest-api)

For your second question,
Yes this is also possible, Just giving the parameters within the body

**DevOps Body**

```
{
    "parameters":  "{\"Parameter1\":  \"a value\"}",
    "definition":  {
                       "id":  2
                   }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36339920/7073340)

*Note: For these API calls make sure you use Basic Auth and pass a Personal Access Token as the value*

Comment: Hello Jayendran . I am trying the same for creating release pipeline . But I get page not found . Can you please help .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225115/release-pipeline-api-is-not-working-in-azure-devops

Comment: @bkr glad you got the answer by yourself

Comment: *Important*: In the newest version of the API `parameters` is a string and no JSON object anymore. But the string should contain JSON. So you have to escape a JSON object, like so: `"parameters": "{ \"param1\": \"value1\" }"`

Comment: I am struggling with either methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654387/azure-rest-api-for-building-pipelines

Please help.

Comment: This just isnt working for me, no build is started, no response is given

Answer (score 0):

An full answer for queuing a Build using the [Azure DevOps REST API 7.1 (still in preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), using `cURL`, with PAT (Personal Access Token) authentication and custom parameters:

```bash
YOUR_PAT_TOKEN_ENCODED_IN_BASE64=...
AZURE_ORGANIZATION=...
AZURE_PROJECT=...
PIPELINE_ID=...
FULL_GIT_SHA=... # Optional, see usage below

curl --location \
  --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/$AZURE_ORGANIZATION/$AZURE_PROJECT/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic $YOUR_PAT_TOKEN_ENCODED_IN_BASE64' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
    "definition": {
      "id": "$PIPELINE_ID"
    },
    "sourceVersion" : "$FULL_GIT_SHA", # Optional: only if you want to override the default sourceVersion
    "parameters": "{\"your.parameter\": \"your value\"}" # Yes this is a stringified JSON inside a stringified JSON...
  }'
```

Don't know what your PIPELINE_ID is?
Go to the Azure Pipeline website, click on your pipeline and look at the URL: https://dev.azure.com/yourorganization/yourproject/_build?definitionId=42 -> the `definitionId` is the one you want

Answer (score 0):

I got in here while trying to trigger a Release Pipeline via cURL with PAT and I have some slightly different input that might by handy to somebody else with the same problem.

There's a Build, a Run and a Release API out there, and for this case (trigger a release pipeline), the Release API, create method, should be used:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP
```

Moreover, by trial and error, I've found out that this doesn't work:

```
--header 'Authorization: Basic $PAT_TOKEN_ENCODED_IN_BASE64'
```

Following the Basic Authentication Scheme we have the following pattern:

```
base64(user:password)
```

And for PAT authentication, even though, user is empty, the colon is required so the information is correctly parsed in the Microsoft's API side.

This is what I've ended up doing in bash:

```
AZURE_ORGANIZATION=...
AZURE_PROJECT=...
PIPELINE_ID=...
MY_PARAMETER=...
PAT=...

# IMPORTANT: mind the colon before PAT
PAT_TOKEN_ENCODED_IN_BASE64_WITH_COLON=$(echo -n ":$PAT" | base64)

curl \
  --request POST "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$AZURE_ORGANIZATION/$AZURE_PROJECT/_apis/release/releases?api-version=7.1-preview.8" \
  --header "Authorization: Basic $PAT_TOKEN_ENCODED_IN_BASE64_WITH_COLON" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
      "definitionId": "'$PIPELINE_ID'",
      "variables": {
        "MY_VAR": {
          "value": "'$MY_PARAMETER'"
        }
      }
    }'
```

Last but not least, regarding variables, for Release Pipelines, variables must be declared in Pipeline's Variables Tab and marked as "Settable at release time".

I hope it helps.