# Running an Azure DevOps pipline via CLI or web-hook

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to run (queue) a specific azure pipeline from the command line or via http web-hook or an API ? I would like to automatically trigger a pipeline without the need to change git or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AzureDevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Queue?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1)

**POST:**

```
https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1
```

**Body:**

```
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": number
        } 
}
```

[Refer my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724205/7073340)

Comment: In addition, there are some easy-to-use extensions in the Marketplace, like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenQueueNewBuild and more