# Azure DevOps REST API - Run a pipeline passing branch name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

I have an API that I want to run a pipeline in a specific branch.

In DevOps, you have the option to select a branch/commit that you want to run the pipeline on:

[image]

How can I use this via the REST API - Run a pipeline request?

[REST API - Run pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Is there any parameter in request body that allows me to define it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question is for the builds api, this is for the pipelines api

Comment: You can accomplish this via the resources property in the body, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63656775/892770:

{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "<your-branch-name>"
            }
        }
    }
}