# API for automating Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to automate the queue-ing of Azure Pipelines with an API call, get information on the pipeline/build/job status,

1. Azure Pipelines docs only mention "API" for the "Invoke HTTP Rest API" task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=vsts That might come in handy, but is not what I am looking for.
2. There is a "Azure DevOps Services REST API":
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
   But I couldn't find any mention of "Pipeline" there, so this doesn't seem to be the right thing as well.

   The StackOverflow tag `azure-devops-rest-api` also only mentions VSTS and TFS:

   > Visual Studio Team Services REST APIs is a set of APIs allowing management of a Visual Studio Team Services accounts as well as TFS 2015 and 2017 servers.

Besides these two results, I only find other versions or translations of various copies of these - and a lot of unrelated documents that are about Azure in general.

Am I just using the wrong words to search?

---

Is there an actual API for Azure DevOps Pipelines?
Does it have a usable API Explorer?
Does it have proper clients for languages like JavaScript, Ruby or PHP?

Comment: Powershell support:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems I was bad at googling:

[Trigger Azure Pipelines build via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718462/trigger-azure-pipelines-build-via-api) and [Start a build and passing variables through VSTS Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343084/start-a-build-and-passing-variables-through-vsts-rest-api) (found via the searching for `[azure-pipelines] api`here on StackOverflow) point me to the Azure DevOps Services REST API that I had mentioned above.

Comment: Submitted a review to change the `azure-devops-rest-api` tag.

Comment: You can use the AzurePipelinePS powershell module to make the api calls. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS

Answer (score 5):

I too have been working on automating DevOps pipelines and keep winding up back here.  Some of this information appears to be outdated.  As of the time of my writing this, I believe [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in the Microsoft Docs is the most recent.  I did have to scratch my head a bit to make it work, but wound up with this code

```cs
public static async Task InitiatePipeline(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var token = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", AppSettings.DevOpsPAT)));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);

var repoGuid = "Put GUID Here"; // You can get GUID for repo from the URL when you select the rpo of interest under  Repos is Project Settings
var bodyJson = @"{
    ""parameters"": {
        ""parameterName"": ""parameterValue""
    },
    ""variables"": {},
    ""resources"": {
        ""repositories"": {
            ""self"": {
                ""repository"": {
                    ""id"": """ + repoGuid + @""",
                    ""type"": ""azureReposGit""
                },
                ""refName"": ""refs/heads/master""
            }
        }
    }
}";

        var bodyContent = new StringContent(bodyJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var pipeLineId = 61; // Can get this from URL when you open the pipeline of interest in Azure DevOps
        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_apis/pipelines/{pipeLineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1", bodyContent, cancellationToken);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe for the pipelines run API, it should be "templateParameters", not "parameters". At least for me, it did not work with "parameters".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into these problems as well and wound up making a powershell wrapper of the API and then wrapping that into an Azure DevOps Pipeline Template. I've just published it for anyone to use. I hope that anyone who finds this thread can find [this template](https://github.com/lifesoccult/azure-devops-run-pipeline) useful.

Answer (score 0):

With [AzFunc4DevOps](https://github.com/scale-tone/AzFunc4DevOps#azfunc4devops) this can be done in an event-driven way. And in C#.

E.g. here is how to trigger a build when another build succeeds:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(TriggerBuildWhenAnotherBuildSucceeds))]
public static async Task Run(
    [BuildStatusChangedTrigger
    (
        Project = "%TEAM_PROJECT_NAME%",
        BuildDefinitionIds = "%BUILD_DEFINITION_ID%",
        ToValue = "Completed"
    )] 
    BuildProxy build,

    [BuildClient]
    BuildHttpClient buildClient,

    [BuildDefinition(Project = "%TEAM_PROJECT_NAME%", Id = "%NEXT_BUILD_DEFINITION_ID%")]
    BuildDefinitionProxy nextbuildDefinition
)
{
    await buildClient.QueueBuildAsync(new Build
    {
        Definition = nextbuildDefinition,
        Project = nextbuildDefinition.Project
    });
}
```

Here are [some more examples](https://github.com/scale-tone/AzFunc4DevOps/tree/main/samples#azfunc4devops-samples).