# How do I write an azure function to trigger a azure devops pipeline? Is this even possible?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm trying to set up an Azure function that can trigger a Azure devops build pipeline. But I'm not sure on how to proceed with this and if it's even possible to do so.

I already have a build pipeline ready to be used but the conventional triggers that are already provided by Azure devops cannot be used. I can't disclose the reason but I need to trigger it using an Azure function. Any help regarding this would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the REST APIs of Azure DevOps and call those from your function. See here: [API for automating Azure DevOps Pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726566/api-for-automating-azure-devops-pipelines)

Answer (score 1):

**How to proceed with this and if it's even possible to do so.**

Of course, it can do to trigger a Azure Devops pipeline by Azure function.

To achieve this, you will use Visual Studio also, better with the version 2017 or higher , and also installed .Net Core SDK and [Develop Azure Functions using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs).

1. In the Azure Function App you created, open **HttpTrigger1**, and
   click **Get Function Url**.  This is a key point, so better save
   it in the txt. Because as this execution, Azure Function just act as
   a switching proxy or mechanism.
2. Create a Azure Function project in Visual studio. In template,
   choose **HttpTrigger** template, **Azure Functions v1 (.NET
   Framework)** from the framework dropdown.
3. Open `.cs` file and input the below script in it:

   ```
         using System;
         using System.Linq;
         using System.Net;
         using System.Net.Http;
         using System.Threading.Tasks;
         using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
         using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
         using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
         namespace PartsUnlimited.AzureFunction
        {
        public static class Function1
        {
            [FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp1")]
            public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route =
   null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
            {
                var userIdKey = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs().FirstOrDefault(q =>
   string.Equals(q.Key, "UserId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                var userId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIdKey.Value) ? int.MaxValue : Convert.ToInt64(userIdKey.Value);
                var url = $"https://<<APIAppServiceUrl>>/api/{(userId > 10 ? "v1" : "v2")}/specials/GetSpecialsByUserId?id={userId}";
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    return await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                }
            }
        }
       }
   ```
4. Replace `<<APIAppServiceUrl>>` with your **AzureWebsite.net** URL.
5. Go xxxxWebsite->Controllers->StoreController.cs, replace the **url**
   variable in **line 46** with your **Function url** which copied in Step 1.
6. Click **Commit and Push All** to push the changes to the Azure
   Devops repository.
7. Create a build pipeline, and enable CI. And also, create release pipeline, add deloy Azure App task and enable CD.

That's all the steps you need to create. There has been a [blog](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/#create-the-required-azure-resources) which written by our Azure DevOps Labs and it has the detailed steps, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

REST API can be easily invoked from an azure function.

You can pretty much deploy a whole infrastructure as well as deploy the code just based on a function call using azure DevOps.

Refer this for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/