# How do you authenticate an Azure Functions app to use Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-devops-rest-api

Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513638/how-do-i-write-an-azure-function-to-trigger-a-azure-devops-pipeline-is-this-eve); I've started working on an Azure Functions app that'll trigger AzDO build pipelines, but am having trouble authenticating via Oauth. I'm either getting a 203 Non-Authoritative Information status code, or a 400 bad request so far. I've gotten it to work with a personal access token, but would rather have users log in via Azure AD and authenticate that way.

I've tried using the instructions from [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops), registering the app and sending requests to the auth and token URLs to no avail.

Is the best option to perform something similar to [Service to service calls on behalf of the user](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Service-to-service-calls-on-behalf-of-the-user), or is there another option I'm missing? Any help and/or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you have try this Azure DevOps oauth sample? https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT I have, but haven't figured out how to get the Az Function to generate the browser popup for the user to login; it currently also just returns a 203 status code and continues

Comment: Could you please share a simple sample of your code, then I will check where the error is.